# NavMesh moving is not smooth

Tags: unity, c#, navmesh

I have two car in game one of them is cop that chase player, i put a NavMesh on cop with these values:
[image]

when the cop get close to player (player speed is 10 ) , movement will go jittery and not smooth.
Note: cop will not collide with player because i have changed stopping distance in script instead of editor.
Note 2: this jittery movement is not only in camera its also on scene view.
now how i must make movement smoother? where is the problem?

Comment: Can you show a small video/gif of the jittery movement?

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem.. At first i was not sure what was causing the problem but just today i came to realize that the problem was the navmesh agent itself so i moved the object using rigid body instead of navmesh agent and then it was all good

Comment: Please explain what was wrong with the navmesh. The Asker is attempting to use the Nav Mesh Agent, and any answer should also use the agent to be useful.